# How to pull images locally so I'm not repeatedly pulling from Docker Hub

Tags: docker, dockerhub

I'm doing local testing for which I'm repeatedly installing and uninstalling an application. The application install script I'm using uses Docker Hub to pull the image (when I uninstall, it seems to purge the image from local).

Is there a way I can pull down the images and have them persist locally so every time I uninstall/reinstall the app, it finds the image locally first and I don't run out of my docker quota  so quickly?

Bonus - is there a way to do this somehow so the images I pull will automatically update if there's a newer version on Docker Hub?

Comment: May be your uninstall script has `docker image rm` command, which removes all the images in your local. Regarding Bonus - It is possible to pull recent image if u have tagged it as `latest`:

Comment: You might be on to something! Here's the uninstall script I use https://caprover.com/docs/troubleshooting.html (all the way at the bottom). How would I modify it so that it doesn't remove local images?  Thanks in advance @HarishVijayamohan

Comment: I see the command ‚docker system prune —all‘ all the way down in the link that you provided. This command removes all unused containers, images , networks etc. If u like to remove everything except images, then u can perform delete on containers, networks etc manually using other docker commands. For more details hav a look at this [doc](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/system_prune/#examples).

Answer (score 0):

Normally if the docker image with a tag that you are using is not changed in dockerhub, it will not pulled again. It should still there on your local machine, maybe it was somehow deleted by your uninstall process.

Anyway you can also setup a local private docker repository, take a look at something like Nexus from https://sonatype.com

Comment: Hmm for some reason it gets pulled down every time....